# Using Flutter level_map package, trying to perform an action on level tapping. How can I implement that?

Tags: flutter

I'm using this flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/level_map
I can't figure out how to make an action (like printing the level number in the console) by tapping on one of the levels.
From what I've researched, it's complicated because the guy that made the package used a custom painter... for all of the map. So i can't quite find the coordinates of the level icons if i tried, and i can't simply add a GestureDetector either.

What I did until now is take the lib of the package and add it to my project so that I have more customization power over its content.
Does anyone have any suggestions? (or a project that uses this package and achieved to make the levels tappable, or ultimately another customizable map package for me to use)
This is the last working version of my project:
https://github.com/913-Duma-Luana/ProiectLicenta

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.